# Query Unix time by day in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I currently store a timestamp like this:

```
datetime = int(time.mktime(_scheduled_datetime.timetuple()))
> 1172969203.1
```

I need to then find all objects with a datetime of now().

Unfortunately, my application does not allow me to query ranges, only whole values. Is it possible to store only the days part of a timestamp i.e. 01/01/2016 So I could get all `datetime` values for today().

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean something like this: `datetime.today().date()`?

Comment: @AKS I only want to represent the day, month, and year part of a timestamp, not the time, mins. or hours. is this possible in a timestamp? If so how?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? It would give you the date without the time.

Comment: @AKS yes just when I tried time.mktime(kwargs['scheduled_datetime']).date()) I get expected string or buffer

Comment: Ok this seemsed to work ``int(time.mktime(_scheduled_datetime.date().timetuple()))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
import time
import datetime

timestamp = int(time.time())

# date timestamp
print int(
    time.mktime(
        datetime.date.fromtimestamp(timestamp).timetuple()
    )
)

# iso format date string
print datetime.date.fromtimestamp(timestamp).isoformat()
```